# parameter to another function

Tags: batch-file

I try the following code but when I add the bold row it fails

```
:Is_Error_file_empty
for /f "tokens=1,3" %%x in (%TMPLog%) do (
    if "%%x"=="ERROR" SET err=TRUE(
    **call :a %1**
)

:a
if %1 neq "c" (
    echo echo ERROR: you had an error with copying files,please see in error.log for details.
)
```

Comment: Hi zipi, is this the whole code? Where is the left parenthesis for the  right parenthesis in the bold line?

Comment: "It fails", Aha! It fails and kill the computer or it fails and do nothing or do you get an error message? And where do you place the `call :a %1 )`? It could help to be a bit more precise

Comment: I edit the question. I call to a inside the if statement and it failed I mean exit from the CMD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax at all have some issues
The parenthesis are not balanced and placed at the wrong place.
Perhaps you want to use `%1` in `call :a %1` but I can't see where it comes from.
Perhaps you want to use the second token?
`EXIT/b` should be placed after a code block, else also the following code would be executed.

This code could be a base for further testings.

```
:Is_Error_file_empty
for /f "tokens=1,3" %%x in (%TMPLog%) do (
    if "%%x"=="ERROR" (
        SET err=TRUE
        call :errorInfo %%y
    )
)
exit /b

:errorInfo
if "%1" neq "c" (
    echo echo ERROR: you had an error with copying files,please see in error.log for details.
)
exit /b
```